# Error with the lastpage package

Tags: lastpage

Can somebody help me with this error:

```
LaTeX /b/c12/cWarning:/b/c0/c Reference `lastpage' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.
/b/c4/cOverfull/b/c0/c \hbox (9.14719pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
 [][] 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   w
l.24 \newpage
```

My text in LaTeX is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[portuguese,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}

\hyphenation{ra-dio-gra-fi-a in-dus-tri-al}

%\usepackage{helvet}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=2cm,footskip=1cm,height=23cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Determinar que cada primeiro paragrafo seja também indentado

\newenvironment{tquote}{\begin{list}{}
   {\setlength{\leftmargin}{13mm}
   \setlength{\rightmargin}{0mm}}
   \item[]}{\end{list}}

% \widowpenalty=300
% \clubpenalty=300  

\input{macros}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[c]{%
    \centering
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.5cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
          \hline
          \centering
          \includegraphics[height=1.59cm,width=3.0cm]{logo} &
          \centering
          \Large{PROCEDIMENTO ESPECIFICO DE \\ PROTECAO RADIOLOGICA} \\
          \tiny{SR F.30}&
          \centering
         { \scriptsize 
PER \numero \\REV. \rev \\Data:\data \\Pagina.\thepage \ de \pageref{lastpage}} \tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}
    }

    \fancyfoot[R]{
    \hrulefill \\
    {\scriptsize
    Elaboração: \sprNome \\
    Supervisor de Proteção Radiológica -  \sprRegistro
    }
    }


}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\input{capa}

\newpage 
\tableofcontents

% \mainmatter
% \newpage

\input{Transporte-body}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a problem (error) with [`lastpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage)... Regardless, could you supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can copy-and-paste and replicate the problem? We don't have `macros.tex`, nor any of the other things you `\input`.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me first point out this:

> Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of
>   your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking
>   here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your
>   issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune
>   your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.
>
> Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference
>   if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output,
>   such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in
>   the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example
>   together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise
>   we might not be able to reproduce your problem.

(from [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/6865))

Compiling your MWE I get `LaTeX Error: File ... not found.` for `macros.tex`, `capa.tex`, and `Transporte-body.tex`, followed by several `Undefined control sequence.`-errors.

Nevertheless (if there is no additional issue introduced when loading the missing files), the problem is easily solved:

1. You need to really load the `lastpage` package - in your code the `\usepackage{lastpage}` is commented out (percent-sign before it)!
2. The reference is not `\pageref{lastpage}` but `\pageref{LastPage}`.